# enter data into viewPage from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase

I want to enter data taken from Firebase into the viewpage view, I don't know how?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T77ES.png)

**Mainactivity class**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ViewPager2 viewPager;
List<user> userList;
userAdaptor userAdaptor;
DatabaseReference mydb;
private String TAG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"  " , "Value"));
    userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "example2", "Text"));
    userAdaptor = new userAdaptor(this, userList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(userAdaptor);

    mydb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    try {
        mydb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String thisvalue = dataSnapshot.child("Count").getValue().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Insert your firebase data into Arraylist in your onDataChange block

Comment: Please post your code sample here

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code as

```
mydb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    try {
        mydb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String thisvalue = dataSnapshot.child("Count").getValue().toString();
                userList = new ArrayList<>();
                userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, thisvalue , "Value"));
                userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "example2", "Text"));
                userAdaptor = new userAdaptor(this, userList);
                viewPager.setAdapter(userAdaptor);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: <anonymous ValueEventListener> cannot be converted to Context
                    userAdaptor = new userAdaptor(this, userList);

Comment: check the parameter sequence of "user" class.